# Getting Datetime by Year, Month, Date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to get date by Using Year, Month and Day functions. Example

```
declare @Date smalldatetime
select @Date = Year('20140530') + Month('20140530') + Day('20140530')
```

What I want is to assign @Date = '20140530' as smalldatetime. But I want to do this by means of somwething similar to above expression. How can Ido this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I want to get smalldatetime, I wrote that part to clarify my idea

Comment: why not? If I enter select YEAR('20140530'), it returns 2014

Comment: Whatever. Did you understand what I mean?

Comment: I want to assign @Date = '20140530' by MEANS of Year,Month,Day functions

Comment: @KrunalPatil , why are you continuously deleting your comments?

Comment: i deleted my comments because they were not relevant any more.

Comment: Sorry, but they were not relevant at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead try something like below

```
declare @Date varchar(20)
select @Date = cast(Year('20140530') as varchar) + 
cast(Month('20140530') as varchar) + 
cast(Day('20140530') as varchar)

select @Date
```

results in: `2014530`.

(OR) like below

```
declare @Date VARCHAR(20)
select @Date = cast(Year('20140530') as varchar) + '-' +
cast(Month('20140530') as varchar) + '-' +
cast(Day('20140530') as varchar)

select cast(@Date as smalldatetime)
```

results in: `2014-05-30 00:00:00`

`Year()/Month()/DaY()` functions returns the year/Month/Day as Integer. What you are actually doing can be simulated as below

```
declare @Date smalldatetime
set @Date = 2049

select @Date
```

which will result in : `1905-08-12 00:00:00`

Answer (score 0):

Use Like, `Set` will give the Date in `@Date` instead of `select`

```
declare @Date smalldatetime
set @Date = Year('20140530') + Month('20140530') + Day('20140530')
print @Date
```

Comment: print used to check the result (optional)

Comment: it returns August 12, 1905  for above query. I want May 30, 2014

Comment: SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-2, 0), 107) +' '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-2, 0), 108) AS [Mon DD, YYYY]